# How to remove null character from file content in java

Tags: java, file-io, java-io

I receive an `XML` file from a client. I've another file containing `Base-64` encoded data which I embed in one of the elements in XML file. After doing all this merging, I need to return the content of file either as `string` or a `DOM` object, returning as `InputStream` will not work.

But the resulting merged file has `null character` at the end which is causing issues when file is processed as `XML`. How can I get rid of it. This is how I am merging my files.

```
public Object merge(List<File> files) throws Exception {
    System.out.println("merge with arguments is called");

    if(files == null || files.isEmpty() || files.size()<2){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("File list cannot be null/empty and minimum 2 files are expected");
    }

    File imageFile = getImageFile(files);
    File indexFile = getIndexFile(files);

    File inProcessFile = new File("temp/" + indexFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "") + ".xml");
    File base64EncodedFile = toBase64(imageFile);

    /* Write from index file everything till attachment data to inProcess file*/
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(indexFile).useDelimiter("\\s*<AttachmentData>\\s*");      
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(inProcessFile);
    writer.append(scanner.next());

    /* Write <AttachmentData> element into inProcess file */
    writer.append("<AttachmentData>");

    /* Write base64 encoded image data into inProcess file */
    IOUtils.copy(new FileInputStream(base64EncodedFile), writer);

    /* Write all data from </AttachmentData> element from index file into inProcess file */
    String fileAsString = IOUtils.toString(new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(indexFile)));
    String afterAttachmentData = fileAsString.substring(fileAsString.indexOf("</AttachmentData>"));

    InputStream input = IOUtils.toInputStream(afterAttachmentData);
    IOUtils.copy(input, writer);

    /* Flush the file, processing completed */
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();
    System.out.println("Process completed");
}


private File getIndexFile(List<File> files) {
        for(File file:files){
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
            if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(IDX_FILE_EXT))
                return file;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Index file doesn't exist or cannot be read.");

    }


    private File getImageFile(List<File> files) {
        for(File file:files){
            String extension = FilenameUtils.getExtension(file.getName());
            if(extension.equalsIgnoreCase(IMG_FILE_EXT))
                return file;
        }

        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Image file doesn't exist or cannot be read.");

    }


    private File toBase64(File imageFile) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("toBase64 is called");
        Base64InputStream in = new Base64InputStream(new FileInputStream(imageFile), true);
        File f = new File("/temp/" + imageFile.getName().replaceFirst("[.][^.]+$", "") + ".txt");
        Writer out = new FileWriter(f);
        IOUtils.copy(in, out);
        return f;
    }
```

Please help me understand how I can fix my code which produces null character

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fix the code that produces it, perhaps by removing part or the whole of it.  To find this out, you should ask yourself the following questions:

1. Is the null character already present in the original XML file received from the client?
2. In what position of the XML document does the element that contains the base-64 data appear?
3. In what position of the XML document does the null character appear?
4. Are you decoding the base-64 file in any form?
5. Does the base-64 file contain the null character?
6. If yes, why?
7. What method is used to "merge" the base-64-encoded data into the XML document?

As per information produced later by the OP, and if the file *always* contains the null character, the simplest solution is to replace line:

```
String afterAttachmentData = fileAsString.substring(fileAsString.indexOf("</AttachmentData>"));
```

with

```
String afterAttachmentData = fileAsString.substring(fileAsString.indexOf("</AttachmentData>"),fileAsString.length()-1);
```

However, in the long run it's much better to check with the client if the null character is generated on their end of things and, if so, suggest them to to correct the code that generates it so the XML document is valid.

Comment: @MarioRossi yes the original xml file received from client has `NUL` character at the end. please suggest how to get rid of it

Comment: @MarioRossi, is there a generic way to remove Nul character from file if present rather than assuming that there will always be one

Comment: @Learner  Oh, yes.  In your particular case, `if(  fileAsString.charAt(fileAsString.length()-1) == 0 )` will be true if the file **has** the NUL at the end.